# Как запустить программу, написанную на php, через Java программу?

Tags: php, java

У меня есть программа, написанная на php, и мне нужно, чтобы по мере необходимости программа, написанная на Java, запускала эту программу и получала от неё результаты работы. Напишите, пожалуйста, фрагмент кода на java, как это можно сделать, может нужен какой-нибудь поток ввода-вывода на интерпретатор php... или что-то ещё.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать стандартный `Runtime.exec`
.Например:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec();  
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream);//используйте для получения вывода 
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream);//для ввода

...
```

Comment: Только тут один момент: если вы открыли стрим для чтения вывода приложения, то вы обязательно должны его целиком прочесть иначе дочерний процесс может зависнуть.

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить код:

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php file.php");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Перед запуском проверить, что команда 'php' доступна в любом месте из консоли, или же тогда в методе exec прописать к ней путь.